# How to debug if a constexpr function doesn't run on compile time?

Tags: c++11

For example I have a constexpr function, but I use a runtime variable (not marked as `constexpr`) to take the return value. In this case, I'm not sure whether the function runs on compile time or runtime, So is there any way to debug?

At first I thinked about `static_assert`, but it looks like `static_assert` cannot do this. Then I thought convert the code to assembly code, but it is way too difficult to check the assembly code to figure out.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't have notions of compile time and run time. If you need a constexpr value, designate it as such: `constexpr int x = yourfunc();` The question as posed has no answer as far as the C++ *language* is concerned. A C++ *implementation* may do whatever it pleases as long as the rules of the language are not violated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `C++20` there is no way to directly handle it from the program itself.

With `C++20` you have [std::is_constant_evaluated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated).

If the return type from your constexpr func is a valid non type template parameter, you can force your function to be evaluated in compile time like this:

```
constexpr int func( int x ) 
{
    return x*2;
}

template < auto x > 
auto force_constexpr_evaluation()
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int y = force_constexpr_evaluation<func(99)>();
}
```

If you are using `c++20` already, you can directly force compile time evaluation by using [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval)

Debugging on assembly level should be not so hard.

- If you see a function call to your constexpr func, it is running in run time.
- If you see directly the forwarded value, it was evaluated in compile  time.
- If it is inlined, you should be able to detect it by having the function name associated from the debug symbols to the location of the inlined code. Typically, if you set a breakpoint on the constexpr function and it is *not* always be executed at compile time but inlined, you get a number of breakpoints not only a single one. Even if it is one, it points to the inlined position in that case.

BTW: It is not possible to back port `std::is_constant_evaluated` to older compilers, as it needs some implementation magic.

Comment: You predicted everything I wanna ask further.